# Rails валидации

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

У меня есть даты начала и конца события, нужна валидация, которая не допустит ввода даты конца меньше, чем даты начала. Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Из коробки" таких валидаторов нет, но вообще-то всё, на что вы можете написать проверку произвольным Ruby, можно проверять и в валидации.

Обычно это делается путём вынесения этой валидации в метод и [вызова его через `validate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate). [Способ даже описан в гайдах](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods). Результат будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
validate :timespan_valid?

def timespan_valid?
  unless start_date <= end_date
    errors.add(:start_date, 'is past the end of the event')
  end
end
```

Только убедитесь, что метод не швырнёт в вас исключением в штатной ситуации. Скажем, в штатной ситуации какая-то из дат может запросто быть `nil`'ом. Как на это реагировать, решайте сами.